# How To Append Item In DataSource Swift

Tags: ios, swift, datasource

I have a DataSource file that holds my items. However, I need to append the images property within my `SummaryImagesViewModelItem` how would I go about this with my current model?

### VIEW MODEL CLASS

```
class SummaryImagesViewModelItem: SummaryViewModelItem {
    var type: SummaryType {
        return .images
    }
    
    var header: String {
        return "Photos"
    }
    
    var images: [UIImage]
    init(images: [UIImage]) {
        self.images = images
    }
    
    var itemCount: Int {
        if images.isEmpty {
            return 1
        } else {
            return images.count
        }
    }
}
```

### DATASOURCE

```
class ListingSummaryDataSource: NSObject {
    
    var items = [SummaryViewModelItem]()
    
    init(summary: Summary) {
        super.init()

        if let images = summary.images {
            let imagesItem = SummaryImagesViewModelItem(images: images)
            items.append(imagesItem)
        }

        if let title = summary.title {
            let titleItem = SummaryTitleViewModelItem(title: title)
            items.append(titleItem)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? Why `if images.isEmpty { return 1 }` ?

Comment: I need to append the images property in SummaryImagesViewModelItem

Comment: Did you not added that already?

Comment: No, so this is a form. I have a section of the form where I upload images. I then want to upload these images to a 'post' item. So I need to update the summary model I believe with the additional images.